What is the Carter constant?
The definition in Carter constant doesn't explain it clearly, I understand that

It is a conserved quantity for motion around black holes.

What does "quantity for motion" mean? And with what does it deal?
Can someone introduce it to me? Because I didn't get any information about this topic. All that I found was for the advanced level.

The Wikipedia article you cite has a pretty simple explanation of the Carter constant's exact definition, and "conserved quantity for motion" just means that the constant is constant (conserved) in situations of motions around Kerr black holes. I'm not sure what would qualify as anything but "advanced level" here, given that that already is by your definition. There's no differential geometry in the constant's definition or application, just basic calculus and algebra; what are you looking for exactly?

There is no differential calculus in the finished product, but differential calculus is used in the production process, see here

In very basic terms, the Carter constant is a mathematical quantity that helps about the description and predictability of particle’s motion around a rotating black hole.
There are four quantities which are always conserved around blackholes; the carter constant, energy, axial angular momentum, and the particle’s rest mass. All these conserved quantities are enough to uniquely determine all orbits of the particle in the Kerr–Newman metric (this metric describes a charged rotating mass in space-time).

"All these conserved quantities are enough to uniquely determine all orbits of the particle in the Kerr–Newman metric (this metric describes a charged rotating mass in space-time)." There is typically a finite number of distinct geodesics described by any particular choice for the values of the constants of motion. Typically only one of these is truly an orbit, although there at least some edge case where there are two different types of orbits with the same constants of motion.

Yes, of course, it is true. The question was specifically concerned with the Carter constant, so I abstained from going further into the metric. Thank you for pointing it out!

The square root of the Carter constant has the units of angular momentum. In Schwarzschild it reduces to the covariant angular momentum in the θ direction, while in Kerr it corrects for the frame dragging so it stays constant while the true angular momentum along θ would not be conserved.
Together with the other conserved quantities like total energy and axial angular momentum it helps to bring the 2nd order differential geodesic equations of motion down to 1st order, or you can check the numerical stability of your 2nd order integration by checking if the constants stay constant.
